# WinForms: How to programmatically fire an event handler?

Tags: .net, winforms, events

I want to programmatically invoke an event handler for a control. For example:

```
DateTimePicker dtpLastConsummated;
```

I want to trigger the TextChanged event handler for the `dtpLastConsummated`, how can i do it?

In other languages I would call something akin to:

```
dtpLastConsummated.TextChanged(this, new EventArgs());
```

but in .NET you can have multiple event handlers:

```
dtpLastConsummated.Click +=new EventHandler(dtpLastConsummated_TextChanged);
dtpLastConsummated.Click +=new EventHandler(dtpLastConsummated_AnotherHandler);
dtpLastConsummated.Click +=new EventHandler(dtpLastConsummated_MoreHandlers);
...
dtpLastConsummated.Click +=new EventHandler(dtpLastConsummated_Nminus1);
```

so you need a way to trigger all the attached event handlers.

---

### Answer

The following code will fire the event:

```
Toolkit.FireEvent(dtpLastConsummated, "TextChanged", new EventArgs());
```

And here's the code of the static toolkit function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Programatically fire an event handler of an object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="targetObject"></param>
/// <param name="eventName"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
public static void FireEvent(Object targetObject, string eventName, EventArgs e)
{
   /*
    * By convention event handlers are internally called by a protected
    * method called OnEventName
    * e.g.
    *     public event TextChanged
    * is triggered by
    *     protected void OnTextChanged
    * 
    * If the object didn't create an OnXxxx protected method,
    * then you're screwed. But your alternative was over override
    * the method and call it - so you'd be screwed the other way too.
    */

   //Event thrower method name //e.g. OnTextChanged
   String methodName = "On" + eventName;

   MethodInfo mi = targetObject.GetType().GetMethod(
         methodName, 
         BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

   if (mi == null)
      throw new ArgumentException("Cannot find event thrower named "+methodName);

   mi.Invoke(targetObject, new object[] { e });
}
```

---

**Note:** I'm not creating a subclass of every control in the .NET framework, and every 3rd party control, and convincing an enterprise worth of developers to retrofit every form to use my custom controls.

Comment: Great answer Ian but it would have been better if you'd have put the answer in the Answers section of the page so it could properly be up voted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

3 suggestions to fire the TextChanged Event:

Manually change the text:

```
        string s = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        dateTimePicker1.Text = String.Empty;
        dateTimePicker1.Text = s;
```

or

Inherit from DateTimePicker and create a new method that exposes / calls DateTimePicker's protected OnTextChanged

```
public class MyDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    public void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
}
```

or

If you don't like OOP and want to break encapsulation, you can access the protected OnTextChanged method through reflection:

```
        MethodInfo onTextChanged = dateTimePicker1.GetType().GetMethod("OnTextChanged", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        onTextChanged.Invoke(dateTimePicker1, new object[] { new EventArgs() });
```

Comment: Like every other object library, you can't get very far honoring the encapsulation.

Answer (score 8):

Button in Windows Forms is a special case, because it has a [PerformClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) method to do exactly what you're talking about. For other events in other controls, though, there's really nothing similar.

Comment: Actually, if the code that fires the event is in the method of a subclass of Control, you can use [InvokeOnClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokeonclick(v=vs.110).aspx) like so: `InvokeOnClick(control, new EventArgs())`. Note that it is a protected instance method ([that doesn't use `this`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,852870e05b8c042d)) instead of a public static method as one might expect.

Answer (score 4):

You can inherit from that class and create a new method that calls the protected OnSomeEvent() method.

```
class MyButton : Button
{
    public void CauseClick()
    {
        this.OnClick();
    }
}
```

As Matt pointed out, you can use PerformClick() for this specific example. However, most events don't have corresponding public functions to trigger them.

Answer (score 0):

**Following code helped me to fire event**

```
ddlTopic_SelectedIndexChanged(this, new EventArgs());
```

**Actual Event**

```
private void ddlTopic_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do something
}
```