# Is there an event that fires after load for a user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using User Controls in C# winforms, and I would like some code to be executed after the load event, and after the control has been shown.  If no such event exists, is it possible to make one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UserControl Load event not fired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220483/usercontrol-load-event-not-fired)

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to accomplish?  Why does it have to be run after "the control has been shown"? (does that mean after the control has been created or after the user has seen the control?)  What does this code do?  Without more information it is hard to know what event will give you what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of events from [this list.](http://codebetter.com/paullaudeman/2005/04/17/windows-forms-basic-events-in-the-lifecycle-of-forms-and-controls/) `OnPaint` would be most likely candidate.

Form Events:

Construtor
Load
Layout
Activated
Paint­
Closing
Closed
Deactivate
Dispose

and for Controls:

Enter
GotFocus
Leave
Validating
Validated
LostFocus

If you can't find one that fits you needs, this article [explains how to construct and fire event.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372974/winforms-how-to-programatically-fire-an-event-handler)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a public method in user control
2. Call the method on Parent win-form [Shown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This will call the code you want to run once.

You can also use user-control paint event, but this will Expensive call. Because your code will execute every time the control is redrawn.

So it is better to use a flag which you can determine whether to run the code or not

i.e.

```
  private bool _run =true;

  private void Control_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!_run) return;
            //call the code you need to run
           _run = false;
        }
```

Comment: Don't care for parents having to call the user control for this to work, but the second idea of flagging the first call to Paint looks valid.