# How to call an event handler from another method

Tags: c#, events, methods

Given the following event handler code:

```
private void image1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ///////////
        }
```

How can I call it from another method:

```
 private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            image1_MouseDown(object,  e); // error

        }
```

Comment: Please translate to English

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its in Russian

Comment: Post instead at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: ok
I translate on English
Sorry guys)((((

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696893/how-to-fire-click-event-of-panel-programmatically

Comment: I just provided a translation as well; this question has nothing to do with mouse clicks or timers, and should be closed as duplicate, based on the link in the comment posted by  @LGSon

Comment: private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            image1_MouseDown(image1, EventArgs.Empty);

        } ?????

Comment: Since the question is put on hold for unclear, here is an answer. Use: `image1_MouseDown(sender,  e);` because `object` is a class type, not an instance reference. You can pass any instance you want as `image1` to swap the sender for example, even `null`.

Comment: image1_MouseDown(sender, e); ///error

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers are regular methods like any others.

The reason you can't call it like you're trying to do, is because the `MouseDown` event takes a `MouseButtonEventArgs` instance, while the `Tick` event of timers take the base class `EventArgs`.

You'll need to create a new instance of `MouseButtonEventArgs`, but then you'll need to initialize it with a device, and other event data.

A better option would be to refactor the body of the `MouseDown` event handler to a method taking individual parameters, which you can then call without having to create a `MouseButtonEventArgs` instance.

```
private void image1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.ProcessImageMouseDown(e.ChangedButton, e.ButtonState, e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement));
}

private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ProcessImageMouseDown(MouseButton.Left, MouseButtonState.Pressed, new Point(10d, 20d));
}

private void ProcessImageMouseDown(MouseButton button, MouseButtonState state, System.Windows.Point position)
{
    // Do actual processing here.
}
```